# Can't Build Android Project After moving package folder

Tags: android-studio, build

I can't build my Android project everytime I try I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
```

please help

**EDIT**

I have realized that I had a package folder called "services" and it was under my folder **app>java** but I want to move it to **app>java>com.package.name** but I get that error. How do I move the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move your package. First Right clik on the given package then:

1. Refactor
2. Move
3. Move Package
4. Specify the exact destination where you want your package to be moved(make sure **search in comment and strings** and **search for text ocurences** are checked to prevent future errors)
   5.(Optional) You can tap on Preview to see what will be affected by this change.
5. If you haven't clicked on Preview, just refactor. If you already clicked on Preview: Do refactor.

I hope this helps.